# How to use Google Map's V2 MapView for Android to display the actionbar?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-mapview

I am trying to display the actionbar above Google Maps, but I realize that once Google Maps open, it is not using my app, but Google's app, therefore the title bar disappears.

I understand that using a MapView allows me to achieve this but I'm not sure how to transition from using a fragment to a MapView as I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

Here's the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.test" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My activity_map.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="org.test.MapActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:cameraTargetLat="35.25215"
    map:cameraTargetLng="-112.24659"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="true" />
```

My activity_mapview.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

My MapActivity.java:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
  private GoogleMap mMap;
  private MapView mapView;
  private Marker marker;

  private static final LatLng ONE = new LatLng(32.882216, -117.222028);
  private static final LatLng TWO = new LatLng(32.872000, -117.232004);
  private static final LatLng THREE = new LatLng(32.880252, -117.233034);
  private static final LatLng FOUR = new LatLng(32.885200, -117.226003);

  private ArrayList<LatLng> coords = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
  private static final int POINTS = 4;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapview);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }

  private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
      Log.d("Test", "GO HERE");
      mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
      Log.d("Test", "GO THERE");
      if (mMap != null) {
        coords.add(ONE);
        coords.add(TWO);
        coords.add(THREE);
        coords.add(FOUR);

        setUpMap();
      }
    }
  }

  private void setUpMap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < POINTS; i++) {
      mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coords.get(i))
          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    }
  }
}
```

The styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Backward-compatible version of ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle -->
    <style name="ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Backward-compatible version of ?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle -->
    <style name="ButtonBarButton" />
```

Based on doing some log statements, it appears as though `GO HERE` is printed out but it never reaches `GO THERE`, so the issue lies in the following code, but I'm not sure how to fix it, as I'm new to Android programming:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

Logcat:

```
08-21 01:29:20.593  30698-30698/org.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org./org.test.MapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at 
org.test.MapActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapActivity.java:183)
                at 
org.test.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:77)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks.

Comment: where do you get NullPointerException, can you post your stack track(logcat)

Comment: added logcat if it helps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define dependencies in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

For getting title extend your activity from AppCompatActivity and set title with `setTitle()`

For using MapView you don't need to make any checks in onResume.
Just get your map by async method in onCreate.
This `setUpMap` method will be called when map is ready.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private MapView mapView;
    private Marker marker;

    private static final LatLng ONE = new LatLng(32.882216, -117.222028);
    private static final LatLng TWO = new LatLng(32.872000, -117.232004);
    private static final LatLng THREE = new LatLng(32.880252, -117.233034);
    private static final LatLng FOUR = new LatLng(32.885200, -117.226003);

    private ArrayList<LatLng> coords = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    private static final int POINTS = 4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapview);
        setTitle("My Map");
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                setUpMap(googleMap);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    private void setUpMap(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        coords.add(ONE);
        coords.add(TWO);
        coords.add(THREE);
        coords.add(FOUR);
        for (int i = 0; i < POINTS; i++) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(coords.get(i))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pangu what title bar? and why it is a map problem? :) and why minus?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I would like to display a title bar above the map, but my code, as well as your code displays the map on the whole screen, which is why I was asking how to use a MapView because a MapView allows me to achieve this.

Comment: @Pangu but we solved NullPointerExcteption? What title bar do you want? Standard android action bar, or toolbar now?

Comment: basically I am trying to follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sb1oqaptlWQ at the end you can see he has a title bar with the title "My Map"...how can I achieve that with my code? thanks

Comment: @Pangu its not about mapview or mapfragment. show your @style/AppTheme

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87640/discussion-between-pangu-and-pengrad).

Comment: @Pangu i edited my answer. now you will see action bar

Comment: I am trying this code and I am getting an error cannotResolveMethod getMapAsync() .. how can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

There is one major problem here, don't use the `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` in your `activity_mapview.xml` rather include the `MapFragment` in your `activity_mapview.xml` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="org.test.MapActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:cameraTargetLat="35.25215"
    map:cameraTargetLng="-112.24659"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

or use a `FrameLayout` and replace it with the `SupportMapFragment`, let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm trying to use a MapView, not go back to a Fragment.

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused, aren't you trying to use maps?

Answer (score 0):

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        map = fm.getMap();
        if (map != null) {
       //Do some thing here

          }
```

map declaration should be outside of if condition

Answer (score -1):

please change setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapview) to setContentView(R.layout.activity_map).

Because here

```
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
```

you did not inflate layout which contains this fragment.

Comment: Then I would be using the fragment within activity_map.xml and I'm trying to use a MapView within activity_mapview.xml

Comment: @Pangu : then change ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap(); to findViewById(R.id.mapView).

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, changing mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap() to mMap = findViewById(R.id.mapView) gives me an error