# cannot resolve 'getMapAsync(this)' while using a map in android studio?parameter "this" is being underlined

Tags: android

this line of code shows error
    `mMapFragment =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
           googleMap = mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`

Comment: remove getActivity()

Comment: do'nt need `getActivity()` if you are in Activity

Comment: just use this.getFragmentManager().findById();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getActivity() cannot find symbol symbol : method getActivity()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407229/getactivity-cannot-find-symbol-symbol-method-getactivity)

Comment: but that too shows error...

Comment: When you remove `getActivity()` did you get any error ??

Comment: ya i am getting error....

Comment: What error paste it in the question..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment));
mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
```

This may helps you

**EDIT 1**

Similar answer refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139614/3981656) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32139614/3981656)

Comment: @SathishKumarJ `getMap` is deprecated now use `getMapAsync`.